# Error in a strongly typed view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 application which uses Devexpress controls.

My first page works fine, but this is not strongly typed.

I get the error "BC30451: 'ViewData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" on my second page which starts with:

```
    @ModelType IEnumerable(Of MyModel.XXX)

    @Code
        ViewBag.Title = "Index"
    End Code

    <h2>Index</h2>
```

The resulting vb code inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.
Is there a problem with the imports???

```
#ExternalChecksum("C:\Work\XXX\Views\FahrzeugMarke\Index.vbhtml","{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}","A585D67D9E053939A220E5FDCF169863")
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     Dieser Code wurde von einem Tool generiert.
'     Laufzeitversion:4.0.30319.235
'
'     Änderungen an dieser Datei können falsches Verhalten verursachen und gehen verloren, wenn
'     der Code erneut generiert wird.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports DevExpress.Utils
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxNavBar
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxRoundPanel
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxSplitter
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeView
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl
Imports DevExpress.Web.Mvc
Imports DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI
Imports MvcMiniProfiler
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Helpers
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
Imports System.Web.Mvc.Html
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.WebPages

Namespace ASP

    Public Class _Page_Views_FahrzeugMarke_Index_vbhtml
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage(Of IEnumerable(Of myModel.XXX))

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
        End Sub

        Protected ReadOnly Property ApplicationInstance() As ASP.global_asax
            Get
                Return CType(Context.ApplicationInstance,ASP.global_asax)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub Execute()

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))


            #ExternalSource("C:\Work\XXX\Index.vbhtml",3)

    ViewBag.Title = "Index"
```

Comment: P.S.: if I delete the ViewBag.Title = "Index" line, I get an error "Html is ambiguous" as it is defined in System.Web.WebPages AND System.Web.Mvc which are both imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem:

I created the view with MvcScaffolding and the file was saved with ANSI encoding. However, there were German umlauts in my model class name and these got corrupted.

Changing the file encoding to UTF8 solved the issue...